# Creating a proof for ∴∀x(Fx→Gx)→(∃xFx→∃xGx)

Tags: logic

Construct a proof for the argument: ∴ ∀x(Fx → Gx) → (∃xFx → ∃xGx)

1       ∀x(Fx → Gx)
2           ¬(∃xFx → ∃xGx)

This is as far as i've gotten
Im not really sure where to go from here

I have to do the proof on proof-checker.org

These are the rules im allowed to use:

- modus ponens  ->E
- modus tollens MT
- modus tollendo ponens DS
- double negation   DNE
- addition  vI
- adjunction    ^I
- simplification    ^E
- bicondition   <->I
- equivalence   <->E
- repeat    Rep
- conditional derivation    ->I
- reductio ad absurdum  RAA
- universal instantiation   AE
- universal derivation  AI
- existential instantiation EE
- existential generalization    EI

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software or the latin, but you'll probably be better off taking $\exists xFx$ as your second premise

Comment: Yea I think I realized that as well, not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 3):

A proof that passed proof-checker, using [this list of rules](https://proof-checker.org/rules.html):

$$\begin{array}{|rll}
&\rlap{\begin{array}{|rll}
1 &\forall x (Fx\to Gx)\\
\hline
&\rlap{\begin{array}{|rll}
2 &\exists x\ Fx\\
\hline
&\rlap{\begin{array}{|rll}
3 &Fc\\
\hline
4 &Fc\to Gc & \text{1, Universal instantiation}\\
5 &Gc & \text{3, 4, Modus Ponens}\\
6 &\exists x\ Gx & \text{5, Existential generalization}
\end{array}}\\
7 &\exists x\ Gx & \text{2, 3-6, Existential instantiation}
\end{array}}\\
8 &\exists x\ Fx \to \exists x\ Gx & \text{2-7, Conditional derivation}
\end{array}}\\
9 &\forall x(Fx\to Gx) \to (\exists x\ Fx \to \exists x\ Gx) & \text{1-8, Conditional derivation}
\end{array}$$

The same proof as an image, and with rule names that are better aligned:

[image]

Started working on this since a previous and deleted question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4504345/89922

Comment: Ah that's where my issue was, I was not thinking about a subproof under line 2
Thank you :)

Comment: @WoodsStashGang In the [list of rules of that tool](https://proof-checker.org/rules.html), I see subproof and "Conditional derivation" the only way to create a $\to$.

Comment: Yea I was thinking I could do Ex Fx and from there get Ex Gx, I just completely forgot

Answer (score 1):

That's not the best path to take.

When attempting to derive a conditional statement, the optimal approach is to *assume the antecedent* aiming to *derive the consequent*, so that you might use the **Conditional Introduction** rule.

You wish to derive a conditional statement whose consequent is also a conditional statement.

Therefore, you should try nesting conditional subproofs.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~\forall x~(Fx\to Gx)}{\fitch{~~2.~\exists x~Fx}{\quad\vdots\\~~~~.~\exists x~Gx}\\~~~~.~\exists x~Fx\to \exists x~Gx\hspace{22ex}{\to}\mathsf I}\\~~~~.~\forall x~(Fx\to Gx)\to(\exists x~Fx ~\to~\exists x~Gx)\hspace{4ex}{\to}\mathsf I}$$

Now consider how you might introduce that existential quantifier, when you have a universal and existential statement in the assumptions ...